# Fading Text Input Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, text

I am trying to find a script that would let me do what YP.com does. If you look at the business search input it says Business Name or Category. Then if you click on it, the text fades a little, and when you type words, it fades completely. How would I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will you be using a javascript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this jQuery example :

http://www.benwatts.ca/2008/07/19/jquery-input-text-replacement/

Declare 2 CSS classes :

```
.black{
    color:black;
}
.grey{
    color:grey;
}
```

The default CSS class for your input can be the black class.

Like in the link above :

- Use the focus event for changing the CSS to the grey class
- Use the blur event for changing the CSS to the black class
- Add the onKeyDown event to delete the original value and change the CSS to the black class.

Comment: You wouldn't need the blur event because you would change the text back to black with the onkeydown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onfocus` to do the first fade. Then `onkeydown` and fade completely.